# Unable to install Statsmodel

Tags: python, tensorflow, data-science, statsmodels

I am getting error when i try to install statsmodel.
I have installed all dependencies required for statsmodel.
[Error message when using CMD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DoDuq.png)

[Unable to find the reason for this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D0t44.png)

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing issues in installing statsmodel .
you can use Anaconda navigator and follow the following steps.

- Clone the statsmodels repository using 
   "git clone git://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels.git"
- Inside statsmodel build the setup file using "python setup.py build"
- Install it using "python setup.py install"
- Restart the  terminal in your environment.

  you may also face error Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools. 
  link : 
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=691126&fixForIE=.exe.
  Hope it helps.